# React-native navigation with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm new in React-native and Redux. I'm planing to use a **Navigator** component for navigation. For example, there is a button. When it's pressed, the app will navigate to another view. I'm wondering whether I should  call **push** directly in **onPress** or I should call **dispatch** first then call **push** based on the state?

**P.S.**

For example, I have 3 components. One is container (**LaunchContainer**):

```
export default class LaunchContainer extends Component {
  renderScene(route,navigator) {
    return <route.component {...route.passProps}
      title={route.name} navigator={navigator} />
  }

  render() {
    const initialScreen = FrontScreen
    return (
      <Navigator style={{flex:1}}
        initialRoute={{name:'Launch',component:initialScreen}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene} />)
  }
}
const screenSelector = (store) => {  
  return {
    inLoginScreen: store.launch.isInLoginScreen
  }
}

module.exports = connect(screenSelector)(LaunchContainer)
```

The initial screen inside the container is **FrontScreen**:

```
export default class FrontScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.props.dispatch(switchToLogin())}>
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>LOG IN</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

When **login** button clicked, I want to launch the **LoginScreen** through **LaunchScreen**. As you see, when user click the login button, the an action will be dispatched then the **selectScreen** function is called by reducer.

My question is how and when I should push a **Login** component?

Answer (score 1):

You dispatch actions within your components. You could use sagas for example to listen for specific actions from your store and execute promise based (async) operations afterwards.

```
function* saga_example() {
   yield take('CHANGE_TO_HOME_SCENE')
   yield put({ type: 'SHOW_WAITING_MODAL' })
   const response = yield call(expensiveFunction)
   yield put({ type: 'EXPENSIVE_RESULT', response.data})
   yield put({ type: 'HIDE_WAITING_MODAL' })
}
```